# A Data Cube using single Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, analysis, olap-cube, degenerate-dimension

I have a single table of data that consists of 40 cols. Everything I need is in there.
I was wondering if I could Build a Data Cube on this table alone.

How can I say to the cube that these are the dimensions, these are Measures?

Could you please tell me the process?

---

I have columns like HouseNo, Date, Time, IndoorTemp, OutdoorTemp, Relay and so on.

All of this data is in one table. I would like to construct a Cube where the dimensions would be HouseNo, Date.

This table has a composite primary key. It consists of (HouseNo,Date,Time)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating degenerated dimensions concept. You will have single table in relational side and you may create separate olap dimension structure for each desired dimension and link them with the fact table using "degenerate dimension linkage".